# Use Vector with Pair

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair

I have code kruskal's algorithm(MST) and use vector of pairs like this

```
vector<pair<int,pair<int,int> > > v;
```

I want to add wight and make source, destination pair like this

```
v.push_back(make_pair(wight,make_pair(src,des)));
```

and then

```
sort(v.begin(),v.end());
```

Since it sort first according to the x-coordinate, then the y-coordinate

and it comes up with errors

```
error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘v’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
   v.push_back(MK(wt,MK(x,y)));
     ^

    error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘v’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
      sort(v.begin(),v.end());
             ^

    error: request for member ‘end’ in ‘v’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
      sort(v.begin(),v.end());
                       ^
```

I am learning how to use c++ STL and tired to debug it. So how can i push pairs and sort this vector?

Link of my code.
https://ideone.com/obEhP0

Comment: `union` is a keyword in C++, you cannot use it as the name for a function.

Comment: @nwp yes i changed it, by the way thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` starts with `int v, e;`. So references to `v` see that`int` rather than your `vector`.

(Aside: those macros. Don't do that. Really. They hinder rather than help readability, and have all sorts of disadvantages.)